# Filtering referenced nodes where logged in user is a member

Tags: views, organic-groups, entities

I am trying to set up a view of referenced nodes (entity reference field) of the current viewed (group)node. 
So when a node is viewed i like to filter all the nodes that point to the current node.

Using the node id from url in contextual filter gives no problems.
So far so good.

However i like to only display those referenced nodes where the current logged in user is a member of.

Is this possible using views?

Comment: Is this (group) node created using Organic Groups module? Are the entity references OG members of the OG group?

Comment: Thank for your help.
Yes i make use of the OG module.
To be more specific:
Content types A and B are both groupnodes and can be referenced to each other by a entity reference field.
When a user is member of both groups he must see a link of group type A on group type B and vice versa.

This way making it possible to switch between both groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for pointing me the right direction.
The next setup is my solution:
"1 Add a Contextual filter on "OG membership: Group ID".

2 When the filter is not available Provide default value "The OG groups of the logged in user ". Leave the concatenator as "+".

3 Under More check "Allow multiple values"

4 Add a second contectual filter choose: content:name of the entity reference field

5 Config this filter with provide default value "Current OG group from context"

6 Under More check "Allow multiple values"

7 Add a relationshiop :OG membership from node group

8 Under the contextual filter:"OG membership: Group ID" add the relationship mentioned under  7

Looks like this is working

Comment: Probably would have been better to accept my solution and update it. But I'm glad you found your fix.

Answer (score 1):

Ok Organic Groups. I got a long way with the following recipe. Unfortunately I could not set up an identical environment to yours.

1 Add a Contextual filter on "OG membership: Group ID".

2 When the filter is not available Provide default value "The OG groups of the logged in user ". Leave the concatenator as "+".

3 Under More check "Allow multiple values"

Comment: "1 Add a Views Relationship (in Advanced) to the current user. 2 A another filter to the View that matches the current user to the Entity References membership field."

How do i set up a relationship to the current user, under relationship there is no user category

So actually i have two entity reference fields on my groupnodes. One is used to determine groupmembership. The other is pointing to a a different groupnode, as in nodereference.

Comment: You're right of course. No user in Relationships. I've updated my answer for Organic Groups and used a contextual filter. YMMV

Answer (score 0):

i edit the text before and working for me

Thanks for pointing me the right direction. The next setup is my solution: "1 Add a Contextual filter on "OG membership: Group ID".

2 When the filter is not available Provide default value "The OG groups of the logged in user ". Leave the concatenator as "+".

3 Under More check "Allow multiple values"

i omitted this step

5 Config this filter with provide default value "Current OG group from context"

6 Under More check "Allow multiple values"

7 Add a relationshiop :OG membership from node group

8 Under the contextual filter:"OG membership: Group ID" add the relationship mentioned under 7

Looks like this is working